# Get SharePoint 2016 workflow inventory with the last run time

Tags: sharepoint-server, workflow, powershell

I am running the below PowerShell script to get the all workflow in a given web application:

```
#For SharePoint 2007 Compatibility
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint")
 
Function global:Get-SPWebApplication($WebAppURL)
{
 return [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebApplication]::Lookup($WebAppURL)
}
 
#Function to Get the workflow inventory for the entire web application
function Get-WorkflowInventory([string] $WebAppURL)
{
    #Get the Web Application URL
    $WebApp = Get-SPWebApplication $WebAppURL 
  
    #Iterate through each site collection
    foreach ($Site in $WebApp.Sites)
          {                             
                #Loop through each site    
                foreach ($Web in $Site.AllWebs)
                   {
                    #Loop through each list
                    foreach ($List in $Web.Lists)
                      {
                         # Leave hidden Lists and Libraries
                         if($List.Hidden -eq $false)
                         {
                            foreach ($WorkflowAssociation in $List.WorkflowAssociations)
                            {
                                #Leave the "Previous Versions"
                                if($WorkflowAssociation.Name.Contains("Previous Version") -eq $false)
                                    {
                                       $data = @{
                                        "Site" = $Site.Rootweb.Title
                                        "Web" = $Web.Title
                                        "Web URL" = $Web.Url
                                        "List Name" = $List.Title
                                        "List URL" =  $Web.Url+"/"+$List.RootFolder.Url
                                        "Workflow Name" = $WorkflowAssociation.Name
                                        "Running Instances" = $WorkflowAssociation.RunningInstances
                                        }
                                         
                                        #Create a object
                                        New-Object PSObject -Property $data
                                    }
                              }
                          }                   
                    }
                     $Web.Dispose()                 
                }
                $Site.Dispose()                  
    }
}



#call the function
Get-WorkflowInventory "http://sharepoint.crescent.com" | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path D:\Reports\WorkflowInventory.csv
 
write-host "Workflows Inventory report has been generated successfully!"
```

The above script is working fine which gives the output with the below columns:

- Site
- Web
- Web URL
- List Name
- List URL
- Workflow Name
- Running Instances

In the above report, I want to include the **workflow last run/execution time** - how can we do that as we don't see any property with the last run/execution time in $WorkflowAssociation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have [LastUpdated property](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-csom/dn624265(v=office.15)) in workflowInstance class which you can have a try.

Examples:
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/How-get-the-workflow-7d00eed9

[Get the SharePoint 2013 workflow execution status for all the workflows in a Site](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/209500/get-the-sharepoint-2013-workflow-execution-status-for-all-the-workflows-in-a-sit)

Comment: Hi - Thanks for your reply - I understand the LastUpdated property part of the workflow instance which runs on item level - so, it is difficult to scan thru all items in the SharePoint web application as we have lakhs of items. Actually, we wanted to scan our SP 2016 farm to collect all workflows and then decide which workflow is in used or not used at all - so, do we have any tool to do this? I know we have a SharePoint modernization tool, but that runs in SP online not in SP on-premise.